# Subquery in cakePHP to lookup in other table

Tags: mysql, cakephp, subquery

I recently started experimenting with CakePHP. I used this query in "normal" PHP and need to convert it to a CakePHP find. However I can't seem to make it work!

```
SELECT *, 
(SELECT name FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id`=`products`.`creator`) AS creatorname 
FROM `products` 
WHERE `products`.`ID`='2'
```

It's a basic set up with 2 tables, users and products. Every product gets created by a user and I need to load the name of the user along with the product info. (So I can display the username and not just the user id.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the relations set up correctly:

```
$this->Product->find(
    'first',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Product.id' => 2
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            'Product.*',
            'User.name'
        ),
        'recursive' => 1
    )
);
```

Comment: Keep getting `Warning (512): SQL Error: 1051: Unknown table 'User' [CORE/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]`

Answer (score 1):

why do you need the subquery?

```
SELECT Product.*, User.name
FROM products as Product INNER JOIN users as User on (User.id = Product.creator)
WHERE Product.id = 2
```

anyway to make subqueries read the [Complex Find Conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions) in the doc

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Also, conventions state the foreign key should be `user_id` (rather than `creator`) but, if you want to keep that field name, your can specify the correct field in your relations like so:

```
class Product extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array('foreign_key' => 'creator')
    );
}

class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Product' => array('foreign_key' => 'creator')
    );
}
```

Comment: I actually made up a case using fake names for columns but thanks ;)