# Translating a SELECT / IN SQL query to cake find

Tags: cakephp

I have a query along the lines of this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE owner_id IN (SELECT owner_id FROM owners_list WHERE user_id = 1) ORDER BY modified DESC
```

What is the most efficient Cake find call that is equivalent? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 choices:

1) Cake does handle sub-queries, though it is complex:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries

Here's a SO question that has an example:
[Subquery in cakePHP to lookup in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859996/subquery-in-cakephp-to-lookup-in-other-table)

2) Use a join statement: 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables

3) You can just use your query as-is via via [Model::query()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) as long as you sanitize first

I prefer option 2 as it's less prone to errors and I don't have to worry about sanitizing/escaping. And once you get the hang of joins you'll find yourself using them more often.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two finds. I'll assume the model name for your owners_list table is OwnersList:

```
    $user_ids = $this->OwnersList->find('list', array(
        'fields'=>array('id','id'),
        'conditions'=>array(
            'OwnersList.user_id'=>1
        )           
    ));

    $results = $this->Post->find('all',array(
        'Post.owner_id'=>$user_ids
    ));
```